# Why I got strange norm value in es?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I got the explain result:

```
{
    "_index": "scoretest",
    "_type": "test",
    "_id": "2",
    "matched": true,
    "explanation": {
        "value": 0.8784157,
        "description": "weight(content:chinese in 1) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
        "details": [
            {
                "value": 0.8784157,
                "description": "fieldWeight in 1, product of:",
                "details": [
                    {
                        "value": 1,
                        "description": "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
                        "details": [
                            {
                                "value": 1,
                                "description": "termFreq=1.0"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 1.4054651,
                        "description": "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=3)"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 0.625,
                        "description": "fieldNorm(doc=1)"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and my document is :

```
chinese book
```

notice the fieldNorm is 0.625

but follow to:

```
public float lengthNorm(FieldInvertState state) {
    final int numTerms;
    if (discountOverlaps)
        numTerms = state.getLength() - state.getNumOverlap();
    else
        numTerms = state.getLength();
    return state.getBoost() * ((float) (1.0 / Math.sqrt(numTerms)));
}
```

I think it should be 1/sqrt(2) = 0.71428571428571

I found the explain it may be because of decode and encode.

1 But I'm not sure is that indeed because of decode? or my calc mistake?

2 in the formula, what is state.getBoost()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because norms are encoded as [single byte floats](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_4/core/org/apache/lucene/util/SmallFloat.html#byte315ToFloat(byte)). Basically, what happens to the value in case of default similarity is this:

```
double d = 1.0 / Math.sqrt(2);
float f = (float)d;
byte b = SmallFloat.floatToByte315(f);
float bf = SmallFloat.byte315ToFloat(b);
System.out.println(bf);
```

If you will run this code it should return you `0.625`.

setBoost() should be 1.0 unless you set index time boosting for this field in the mapping.